# json_serializable fails to deserialize

Tags: json, flutter, json-deserialization, jsonserializer

I am trying to add json support to my flutter project but has some hard time getting it right.

I love flutter but when it comes to json I wish for gson.

I have created a small project that exemplifies my problem.

Please se https://bitbucket.org/oakstair/json_lab

I get the error
**type 'Match' is not a subtype of type 'Map' in type cast** when trying to run the simple to/from json test.

There is obviously something that I miss here!

Thanks in advance from a stormy Stockholm!

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'json_lab.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Match {
  int home;
  int away;
  double homePoints;
  double awayPoints;

  Match(this.home, this.away, {this.homePoints, this.awayPoints});

  factory Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MatchFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MatchToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Tournament {

  List<String> participants; // Teams or Players.
  List<List<Match>> table = new List<List<Match>>();

  Tournament(this.participants, {this.table});

  factory Tournament.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TournamentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TournamentToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample of the json that you intend to receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just committed a solution to this problem to the repo.

I had to add explicitToJson.

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I cannot see your json data I've made assumptions on the information you've provided on naming the objects. You'll need to change the following to match the json names (case sensitive).

Try the following to create your Match object

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: true) //allow null values
class Match extends Object with _$MatchSerializerMaxin {
  int home;
  int away;
  double homePoints;
  double awayPoints;

  Match({this.home, this.away, this.homePoints, this.awayPoints});

  factory Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MatchFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    map["Home"] = home;
    map["Away"] = away;
    map["HomePoints"] = homePoints;
    map["AwayPoints"] = awayPoints;

    return map;
  }

  Match.fromMap(Map map){
    try{
      home = map["Home"] as int;
      away =  map["Away"] as int;
      homePoints = map["HomePoints"] as double;
      awayPoints = map["AwayPoints"] as double;

    }catch(e){
      print("Error Match.fromMap: $e");
    }
  }
}

Match _$MatchFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  Match match = new Match(
    home: json['Home'] as int,
    away: json['Away'] as int,
    homePoints: json['HomePoints'] as double,
    awayPoints: json['AwayPoints'] as double,
  );

    return match;
}

abstract class _$MatchSerializerMaxin {
  int get home;
  int get away;
  double get homePoints;
  double get awayPoints;

  Match<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
    'Home' : home,
    'Away' : away,
    'HomePoints' : homePoints,
    'AwayPoints' : awayPoints
  };
}
```